# How to find the biggest, second biggest and third biggest number in an array, then display their sequence location?

Tags: java, arrays

I have this so far:

```
public static void highV()
{
    KeyboardReader reader = new KeyboardReader();

    int numVal = 0;

    while (numVal < 3) // Makes sure 3 or more numbers are entered
    {
        numVal = reader.readInt("How many values would you like to enter (3 or more): ");

        if (numVal < 3)
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid Entry");
        }
    }

    int[] dval = new int[numVal];

    int i;
    int j;
    int k;
    int a;
    int high = 0;
    int sec = 0;
    int thr = 0;

    System.out.println();
    for (i = 0; i < dval.length; i++) // Reads in numbers and stores them in an array
    {
        dval[i] = reader.readInt("Enter value number " + (i + 1) + ". ");

    }



    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("List of values: "); 
    for (j = 0; j < dval.length; j++)// Prints out a list of values
    {
        if (j == (dval.length)-1)
        {
            System.out.println(dval[j]);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.print(dval[j] + ", ");
        }

    }
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("There was a total of " + dval.length + " numbers entered.");

    System.out.println();

    for (k = 0; k < dval.length; k++) // Determines the highest second highest and third highest numbers
    {
        if (dval[k] > high)
        {
            int oldSec = sec;
            sec = high;
            thr = oldSec;
            high = dval[k];
        }
        else if (dval[k] > sec)
        {
            thr = sec;
            sec = dval[k];
        }
        else if (dval[k] > thr)
        {
            thr = dval[k];
        }
    }


    for (a = 0; a < dval.length; a++) // Determines sequence location of first second and third highest numbers
    {
        if (dval[a] == high)
        {
            high = a+1;
        }
        if (dval[a] == sec)
        {
            sec = a+1;
        }
        if (dval[a] == thr)
        {
            thr = a+1;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("The highest number was in sequence #: " + high);
    System.out.println("The second highest number was in sequence #: " + sec);
    System.out.println("The third highest number was in sequence #: " + thr);
    System.out.println();
}
```

This works for almost everything, except when the numbers entered are all descending. Example: If you enter 5,4,3,2,1 you get 5,4,3 as answers when you should get 1,2,3.

If you enter 2,18,5,3,1,0,9,100 however you get the correct answer of 8,2,7

Any ideas?

Comment: How are 8,2,7 the three biggest of  2,18,5,3,1,0,9,100 ? they are not even present.

Comment: @PeterLawrey OP has to print the ordinals... Not the numbers themselves.

Comment: @PeterLawrey 100 is 8th in the sequence, 18 is 2nd in the sequence, and 9 is 7th in the sequence

Comment: i don't get it.  Aren't `5, 4, 3` the biggest 3 numbers in `5,4,3,2,1`?  Did you mean to say that you wanted the **smallest** 3?

Comment: @SamIam But 5,4,3 are in positions 1,2,3 (starting 1 instead of 0) Wasn't obvious to me either.

Comment: You should use zero based indices for your example.

Comment: @SamIam 5, 4, and 3 are the first second and third numbers in the list, respectively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this block might be problematic because you're repurposing `high`, `sec`, and `thr` from representing the values of the array to representing the index of the array.

Not only that, but you're depending on `high`, `sec`, and `thr`, being values of the array throughout the loop.

```
for (a = 0; a < dval.length; a++) // Determines sequence location of first second and third highest numbers
{
    if (dval[a] == high)
    {
        high = a+1;
    }
    if (dval[a] == sec)
    {
        sec = a+1;
    }
    if (dval[a] == thr)
    {
        thr = a+1;
    }
}
```

---

after the first iteration, `high` will be `5`,(correct), but you'll set it to `1` which you want to display in your output.

But when you come through the second iteration, and `high` is `1`, and `a`, is `1`,   the condition: `(dval[a] == high)` will be true, but in error, and similar erros will happen throughout that loop.

I would **Strongly** advise using different variables to keep track of the indices of your values than the ones that you use to keep track of your values.

Comment: @user2762533 just use a different variable to represent the index than you use to represent the value.  So instead of converting `high` `sec` and `thr` to their positions in the array, make new variables:  `high_index`, `sec_index`, and `thr_index`.

Answer (score 1):

```
    if (dval[a] == high)
    {
        high = a+1;
    }
    if (dval[a] == sec)
    {
        sec = a+1;
    }
    if (dval[a] == thr)
    {
        thr = a+1;
    }
```

When you're determining the indexes for them, you're reusing the same variable. In the 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 case high is first set to 1 which will match stuff later.

Introduce 3 new variables `highInd`, `secInd`, and `thrInd` and that should fix your issue.

Above the for loop:

```
int highInd=0;
int secInd=0;
int thrInd=0;
```

In the for loop:

```
if (dval[a] == high)
{
    highInd = a+1;
}
if (dval[a] == sec)
{
    secInd = a+1;
}
if (dval[a] == thr)
{
    thrInd = a+1;
}
```

Try this. When you're printing, change the variable names to these.

Answer (score 0):

Took me a bit to write this up, but why not handle all of your processing at once. Get your index values and actual values all in one go. Roll the values down if you find one that is bigger and keep on trucking through the for loop.

**This code isn't tested in full swing, but more of an example to show rolling values down as you find a larger value.**

```
int firstLargest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int secondLargest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int thirdLargest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

int firstLargestIndex = -1;
int secondLargestIndex = -1;
int thirdLargestIndex = -1;

// loop through array, check for a higher value than values 
// that have already been saved, if necessary, roll the values down
// and save the current value
for (j = 0; j < dval.length; j++) { 
    if(dval[j] > firstLargest) {
        thirdLargestIndex = secondLargestIndex;
        secondLargestIndex = firstLargestIndex;
        firstLargestIndex = j;

        thirdLargest = secondLargest;
        secondLargest = firstLargest;
        firstLargest = dval[j];
    } else if(dval[j] > secondLargest) {
        thirdLargestIndex = secondLargestIndex;
        secondLargestIndex = j;

        thirdLargest = secondLargest;
        secondLargest = dval[j];
    } else if(dval[j] > thirdLargest) {
        thirdLargestIndex = j;

        thirdLargest - dval[j];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in an alternative approach, you could create a [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) mapping the numbers to their indexes. E.g.

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < numList.Length; i++)
    map.put(numList[i], i);
List<Integer> sortedList = // get descending list of keys from map
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(numList.get(i) + 1));
```

I like this solution better because it is shorter and thus, IMHO, more readable and easy to debug. It's probably a little slower than yours could be, since it's having other classes do some extra work.

Comment: The OP was more so asking what was wrong with THEIR code, not an alternative way to do it.

Comment: @Cruncher I know, but why not? :) I liked the idea of what they were trying to do, and thought of how I'd probably do it. It can be done in MUCH less code, and much more easily/readable, with a lower chance of a bug (but probably a little slower), IMO, by doing it this way instead of how the OP has it.

Comment: @TimS. Yeah your way is definetly better, but hey im just learning

Answer (score 0):

- Create LinkedList
- Sort
- Pop 3 first items
- Find their id in original array

  ```
  Integer data[] = new Integer[] {10,20,30,40,50,60,71,80,90,91 };
  ArrayList<Integer> originalList = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(data));
  LinkedList<Integer> sortedList = new LinkedList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(data));

  Collections.sort(sortedList,Collections.reverseOrder());

  Integer biggest = sortedList.pop();
  Integer second = sortedList.pop();
  Integer third = sortedList.pop();

  Integer indexOfBiggest = originalList.indexOf(biggest);
  Integer indexOfSecond = originalList.indexOf(second);
  Integer indexOfThird = originalList.indexOf(third);
  ```

Comment: This doesn't account for duplicate numbers does it?

Answer (score 0):

just Ideas :

1- use Integer instead of int

2- create 2 comparators for the sorting order you wish to get the first 3 of

3- use LinkedList and PriorityQueue instead of arrays

to be frank with you i didnt get your point quite well, but for getting the first three that the user entered, you can store the values he enters in a Linked list and get the first three

if you have a certain equation to sort his enteries, you can create a comparator (class that implements the comparator interface) and use an instance of it while creating a priority queue for example (or Sort your list with this comparator) and get the first three elements

if you can clarify more your situation i can help