# How can i find the positions to the three lowest integers in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, loops

I how can I find the positions of the three lowest integers in an array?
I've tried to reverse it, but when I add a third number, it all goes to hell :p
Does anybody manage to pull this one off and help me? :)

EDIT: It would be nice to do it without changing or sorting the original array a.

```
public static int[] lowerThree(int[] a)   {            
    int n = a.length;     
    if (n < 2) throw      
      new java.util.NoSuchElementException("a.length(" + n + ") < 2!");

    int m = 0;      // position for biggest
    int nm = 1;     // position for second biggest
    if (a[1] > a[0]) { m = 1; nm = 0; }
    int biggest = a[m];                // biggest value
    int secondbiggest = a[nm];           // second biggest
    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
      if (a[i] > secondbiggest) {
        if (a[i] > biggest)   {
          nm = m;
          secondbiggest = biggest;     
          m = i;
          biggest = a[m];             
        }
        else    {
          nm = i;
          secondbiggest = a[nm];         
        }
      }
    } // for
    return new int[] {m,nm};   
}
```

EDIT: I've tried something here but it still doesn't work. I get wrong output + duplicates...

```
  public static int[] lowerthree(int[] a)    {
    int n= a.length;
    if(n < 3)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("wrong");
    int m = 0;      
    int nm = 1;
    int nnm= 2;

    int smallest = a[m];                // 
    int secondsmallest = a[nm];           /
    int thirdsmallest= a[nnm];

    for(int i= 0; i< lengde; i++)   {
        if(a[i]< smallest)   {
            if(smalles< secondsmallest)  {
                if(secondsmallest< thirdsmallest)  {
                    nnm= nm;
                    thirdsmallest= secondsmallest;
                }
                nm= m;
                secondsmallest= smallest;
            }  
            m= i;
            smallest= a[m];
        }
        else if(a[i] < secondsmallest) {
            if(secondsmallest< thirdsmallest)  {
                    nnm= nm;
                    thirdsmallest= secondsmallest;
            }
            nm= i;
            secondsmallest= a[nm];
        }
        else if(a[i]< thirdsmallest)    {
            nnm= i;
            thirdsmallest= a[nnm];
        }
    }
    return new int[] {m, nm, nnm}; 
}
```

Comment: Define hell please :)

Comment: You just need one more variable and one more `if`.

Comment: It's really easy and does not require any fancy stuff.  You just have to think it through VERY CAREFULLY, resisting the urge to "just try something" and instead thinking out the logic at each step.

Comment: Understand that you need to keep track of both the positions and the values of the lowest three.  Also, it helps a lot if you initialize the "value" vars to "max positive value" for whatever data type you're scanning.

Comment: Were this C#, the answer would be `a.Select((it, i) => new {Item=it, Index=i}.OrderBy(pair=>pair.Item).Select(pair=>pair.Index).Take(3);` Alas, until Java 8 there's no straightforward equivalent, but the decorate-sort-undecorate approach should apply. That is, map your array to a list of objects that encapsulate the index and the value as properties, sort list that using a comparator that compares the values, pick the first three elements from this list, return the index property of those.

Comment: @millimoose - Not particularly efficient, nor educational.

Comment: A simpler algorithm: make a list of indices. Iterate over the original array, looking for the minimum. When you find a new possible minimum (i.e. an element smaller than the previous found minimum), add its index to the list. In the end, return the last three elements from this list.

Comment: @fuLLMetaLMan: many answer (and the question itself, partially) are about finding the three lowest integer in the array, but the title of the question is about the position of the three lowest integer in the array. Which is your need, the positions or the values?

Comment: @HotLicks Decorate-[thing]-undecorate comes up fairly often in my data-munging. While it might not be the thing this assignment is aiming to teach (although you're grasping with that assumption), it's certainly a useful technique. As for efficiency: meh. It's likely fast enough, and it's easy to see why that algorithm is correct.

Comment: @MPavesi I need to find the positions of the values. Like the code i posted returns :)

Comment: Bah, my second proposed approach will fail if, say, the input array is sorted in ascending order, or in any other case where three elements won't be considered "candidate minimums". (I'll leave the comment there since it might be "close enough" to be salvageable.)

Comment: @fuLLMetaLMan Anyway: you should be clearer on what "goes to hell" means. Include findings from running your code on a debugger and comparing its behaviour to what you'd expect given some dummy input data.

Comment: @millimoose Yeah im sorry. By hell I meant that it got me wrong positions.

Comment: Sounds like a duplicate (near enough) of this problem:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18705446/how-to-find-the-biggest-second-biggest-and-third-biggest-number-in-an-array-th/18705714#18705714

Comment: @fuLLMetaLMan Which wrong positions? For what inputs? Did debugging tell you anything about how those got into the output variables, or why the right positions didn't get there?

Answer (score 3):

Getting the top or bottom k is usually done with a [partial sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_sorting). There are versions that change the original array and those that dont.

If you only want the bottom (exactly) 3 and want to get their positions, not the values, your solution might be the best fit. This is how I would change it to support the bottom three. (I have not tried to compile and run, there may be little mistakes but the genereal idea should fit)

```
public static int[] lowerThree(int[] a)   {            
  if (a.length < 3) throw      
    new java.util.NoSuchElementException("...");

  int indexSmallest = 0;
  int index2ndSmallest = 0;
  int index3rdSmallest = 0;
  int smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
  int sndSmallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
  int trdSmallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

  for (size_t i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
    if (a[i] < trdSmallest) {
      if (a[i] < sndSmallest) {
        if (a[i] < smallest) {
          trdSmallest = sndSmallest;
          index3rdSmallest = index2ndSmallest;
          sndSmallest = smallest;
          index2ndSmallest = indexSmallest; 
          smallest = a[i];
          indexSmallest = i;
          continue;
        }
        trdSmallest = sndSmallest;
        index3rdSmallest = index2ndSmallest;
        sndSmallest = a[i];
        index2ndSmallest = i;
        continue;
      }
      trdSmallest = a[i];
      index3rdSmallest = i;
    }
  }
  return new int[] {indexSmallest, index2ndSmallest, index3rdSmallest};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will have the three lowest numbers, need to add some test cases..but here is the idea

```
int[] arr = new int[3];
    arr[0] = list.get(0);

    if(list.get(1) <= arr[0]){
        int temp = arr[0];
        arr[0] = list.get(1);
        arr[1] = temp;
    }
    else{
        arr[1] = list.get(1);
    }

    if(list.get(2) < arr[1]){
        if(list.get(2) < arr[0]){
            arr[2] = arr[1];
            arr[1] = arr[0];
            arr[0] = list.get(2);
        }
        else{
            arr[2] = arr[1];
            arr[1] = list.get(2);
        }
    }else{
        arr[2] = list.get(2);
    }



    for(int integer = 3 ; integer < list.size() ; integer++){

        if(list.get(integer) < arr[0]){
            int temp = arr[0];
            arr[0] = list.get(integer);
            arr[2] = arr[1];
            arr[1] = temp;
        }
        else if(list.get(integer) < arr[1]){
            int temp = arr[1];
            arr[1] = list.get(integer);
            arr[2] = temp;
        }
        else if(list.get(integer) <= arr[2]){
            arr[2] = list.get(integer);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In simple words, you need to compare every new element with the maximum of the three you have at hand, and swap them if needed (and if you swap, max of the three has to be recalculated).

I would use 2 arrays of size 3 each:

```
  arrValues = [aV1  aV2  aV3]    (reals)
  arrPointers = [aP1  aP2  aP3]  (integers)
```

and a 64 bit integer type, call it `maxPointer`.

I will outline the algorithm logic, since I am not familiar with Java:

```
  Set arrValues = array[0] array[1] array[2]  (three first elements of your array)
  Set arrPointers = [0 1 2]   (or [1  2  3] if your array starts from 1)

  Iterate over the remaining elements. In each loop:

      Compare the Element scanned in this iteration with arrValues[maxPointer]
      If Element <= arrValues[maxPointer], 
                    remove the maxPointer element, 
                    find the new max element and reset the maxPointer
      Else
          scan next element
      End If
  Loop
```

At termination, `arrPointers` should have the positions of the three smallest elements.
I hope this helps?

Answer (score 1):

I'd store the lowest elements in a LinkedList, so it is not fixed on the lowest 3 elements. What do you think?

```
public static int[] lowest(int[] arr, int n) {

    LinkedList<Integer> res = new LinkedList();
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

        boolean added = false;
        //iterate over all elements in the which are of interest (n first)
        for(int j = 0; !added && j < n && j < res.size(); j++) {
            if(arr[i] < res.get(j)) {
                res.add(j, i); //the element is less than the element currently considered
                //one of the lowest n, so insert it
                added = true; //help me get out of the loop
            }
        }
        //Still room in the list, so let's append it
        if(!added && res.size() < n) {
            res.add(i);
        }
    }

    //copy first n indices to result array
    int[] r = new int[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n && i < res.size(); i++) {
        r[i] = res.get(i);
    }

    return r;

}
```

Comment: I think that calling `get(int)` on a linked list is a `O(n)` operation and shouldn't be put into a loop. But that's just me.

Comment: but get(int) will only be called for the first n elements of the list.. if you use the function for finding a lot of lowest elements, that sure would be an issue, but it would also miss the purpose of the function.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way to find the positions of three lowest number in an Array

Example :

```
      int[] arr={3,5,1,2,9,7};
      int[] position=new int[arr.length];
      for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
      {
         position[i]=i;
      }
      for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
      {
        for(int j=i+1;j<arr.length;j++)
        {
          if(arr[i]>arr[j]){
          int temp=arr[i];
          arr[i]=arr[j];
          arr[j]=temp;

          int tem=position[i];
          position[i]=position[j];
          position[j]=tem;
          }
        }
      }
     System.out.println("Lowest numbers in ascending order");

     for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
     {
       System.out.println(arr[i]);
     }

     System.out.println("And their previous positions ");

     for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
     {
       System.out.println(position[i]);
     }
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score -1):

you can do it in 3 iterations.

You need two extra memory, one for location and one for value.

First iteration, you will keep the smallest value in one extra memory and its location in the second. As you are iterating, you compare every value in the slot with the value slot you keep in the memory, if the item you are visiting is smaller than what you have in your extra value slot, you replace the value as well as the location.

At the end of your first iteration, you will find the smallest element and its corresponding location.

You do the same for second and third smallest.

Comment: Your solution runs in O(3n) time. Why not just make each comparison as you traverse the array?

Comment: who thought u algorithms? i said 3 iterations. that is not O(3n).

Comment: 3 iterations through the array, if the array is of length n, is 3n.

Comment: You have a funny definition of "iteration".

Comment: i like being funny for the fun of it.

Comment: @codethulhu By definition of the big O notation, O(3n) is the same as O(n).

Comment: It's certainly linear time, which is what O(n) signifies, but it is not the same as O(n). If you had two solutions, one which ran in O(100n) and one which ran in O(5n), would you just say, "Eh, it doesn't matter."? Both solutions are certainly linear algorithms, but they are not the same time complexity.

Comment: @codethulhu look up the definition, constant factors don't matter. Two algorithms can have a huge run time difference but still be both in the class O(n).

Comment: @Henry would it satisfy your pedantry if I said it was run in O(m*n) time, where m = # of low numbers and n = length of array?

Comment: @codethulhu thats fine, but note that this formula is also true if you do it with one loop.

Comment: @Henry you seem to think that doing it all in one loop takes it from 3n to n, when it doesn't, really. You're still doing 3*n comparisons whether you do 1 loop or 3 loops. Putting it all into one loop just makes the time you spend on each spot 3 times bigger.

Comment: @codethulhu: When describing algorithms using [big O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), constants are disregarded, meaning that `O(3n)` has [the same time complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) as `O(n)`. Writing `O(3n)` or `O(100n)` makes no sense, as it simply represents a function with linear time complexity, period. In practice, there will hardly be any difference between making 3 comparisons in a single iteration vs making a single comparison in each of the three runs.